# store a session variable into mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Right now I have this:

```
 session_start()
$_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['title'];
```

I store a variable from jquery to be preserved in the php session, my question now is ...using mysql_query()...how would I store the SESSION variable in the database? I've been trying to find out a proper way to do this without getting an empty value

the full query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO titles (content, type, url, title) 
VALUES ('$content','7',$url',".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['title'])."')");
```

here is the jquery :

```
var title = $(".hidden").text();            
 $.post("tosqltwo.php", { title: title} );              
 var url = $(".hide").text();       

                $(".button").click(function() {
    var content = $(this).siblings().outerHTML();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tosqltwo.php",
        data: {
            content: content, url: url
        }
    });
});
```

I am able to get the content, url and type. The title remains empty

Comment: You can store *session variable* like any other variable, it doesn't matter where the data came from. Can you store just anything into mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store session variable like any other variable, as zerkms said

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO titles (title) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['title'])."')");
```

in your case

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO titles (content, type, url, title) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($content)."','7','".mysql_real_escape_string($url)','".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['title'])."')");
```

Comment: I insist on omitting single quotes around field name `title` or changing them to the backtick char "`"

Comment: sorry..I was trying to see If I could append that query with the one I have currently...see the edit above....I thought it wasn't going to be so tedious.

Comment: and its still giving me an empty cell.:(

Comment: @Praneet: Okay. you had few errors in your query, answer edited

Comment: `$content` should be escaped as weel

Comment: @zerkms: I'm not sure if he escaped it before or not... but because I see that his $_POST isn't escaped, I'm going to escape it in my edit

Comment: @genesis: according to his question and comments - I bet beer that he did not ;-)

Comment: I did escape the content and url :)

Comment: it isn't my fault. It means that $_SESSION['title'] is empty, $_POST['title'] is empty ....